# javascript with html select box

Tags: javascript

I have select box with default value,i want to retrieve default value and changed value using javascript,Below is my Html Select box:

```
<SELECT ID="TEST" NAME="TEST" ONCHANGE="TEST()">
<OPTION ID="1" VALUE="TEST1" SELECTED/>
<OPTION ID="2" VALUE="TEST2"/>
</SELECT>
```

Regards,
Raj

Comment: -1, based on all the back and forth in the comments below you haven't done a good job of fully explaining what you need.

Comment: @jessegavin :I am working on this last couple of days,still i am not figuring out.All below answers are not suitable.If you have any hints please share.

Comment: your one mistake was saying "default" instead of "previous". Please edit your question and explain what you really mean. :)

Comment: I am sorry that this has been a difficult problem to solve, but communicating your actual needs clearly is the best way to get help here. I would urge you to edit your question with a clearer description of all the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set custom attribute of the element in the onload event of the document:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var oDDL = document.getElementById("TEST");
    oDDL.setAttribute("default_value", oDDL.value);
};
```

Then to read it:

```
function Test() {
    var oDDL = document.getElementById("TEST");
    var strCurrentValue = oDDL.value;
    var strDefaultValue = oDDL.getAttribute("default_value");
    alert("Default value is: " + strDefaultValue + "\n Current value is: " + strCurrentValue);
}
```

Complete code and test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/MbnH7/

Edit: to support more than one drop down, first pass reference in the `onchange` event like this:

```
<select id="TEST" name="TEST" onchange="Test(this);">
```

Then set the custom attribute in a loop:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var arrDDLs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrDDLs.length; i++) {
        var oDDL = arrDDLs[i];
        oDDL.setAttribute("default_value", oDDL.value);
    }
};
```

And the test function also need minor change as it's not getting the drop down as argument:

```
function Test(oDDL) {
    var strCurrentValue = oDDL.value;
    var strDefaultValue = oDDL.getAttribute("default_value");
    alert("Default value is: " + strDefaultValue + "\n Current value is: " + strCurrentValue);
}
```

Updated test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/MbnH7/1/

Edit II: to show the **previously** selected value some name changes are required, plus storing the value every time it's changing. The onload becomes this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var arrDDLs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrDDLs.length; i++) {
        var oDDL = arrDDLs[i];
        oDDL.setAttribute("previous_value", oDDL.value);
    }
};
```

(Only change is the custom attribute name)

And the function becomes:

```
function Test(oDDL) {
    var strCurrentValue = oDDL.value;
    var strPreviousValue = oDDL.getAttribute("previous_value");
    alert("Previous value is: " + strPreviousValue + "\n Current value is: " + strCurrentValue);
    oDDL.setAttribute("previous_value", strCurrentValue);
}
```

(Name change plus setting the custom attribute)

Updated and hopefully final test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/MbnH7/4/

Comment: @Shadow Wizard:It's work?ing good,I have 30 select boxes in one page.How can i do this

Comment: @raj what are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to compare the selected value to the default value when a form is submitted?

Comment: No,I want to send previously selected value and present selected value.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard :I have one question here,What if my page have some other select boxes that is not requird to get previous and present select values.

Comment: @raj just don't call `Test` function in their `onchange` event and nothing will happen - there's nothing wrong in setting the custom attribute even if you won't use it later.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard :Hi Thanks for your answer,I tested by adding few options for all select boxes in your example,I tried it,but it is always giving the default value as test1.I tested like,first i chnaged to test1 to test3.results are good.Again i changed test3 to test2.Again it giving default value is test1,in this case it should return test3 as default. and new value is test2.

Comment: @raj default value means the value that was initially selected for the first time. Do you mean you want the **previous** value selected by the user?

Comment: @Shadow: Initially default selected value is the present vlaue,there is no previous values,When user changd value to test3.test1 should be the previous value and test3 should be the present value,I hope this helps.

Comment: @raj yes I now understand though you should have stated this from the beginning. See my new edit. :)

Comment: @ Shadow Wizard :Sorry shadow,I have to improving my phrasing.Your solution working great.thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

why not have the onfocus event (vs. onload) store the current value.  one solution might be to do something like this:

```
$(t).data("prev",$(t).val())
```

and then have the onchange use that:

```
var oldVal = $(t).data("prev");
```

thus when someone clicks on, or tabs into, the ui element it stores the current state, and then can use that if there is a resulting change. also it would need to change the value if the change was accepted so that if focus was not changed (ie: they stayed in the pulldown and changed the value again) and they changed their mind and chose another option that the state was preserved.

many of the examples that i have seen of this store state in a that seemed to be vulnerable to change/events elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - I answered wrong before - Here's a sample HTML page that does it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function showOptionValue(oSelect) {
    var def;
    for (var i=0; i<oSelect.options.length; ++i) //loop through select options
    if (oSelect.options[i].defaultSelected){ //this option's defaultSelected property is set to true (from HTML: selected="selected")
        def = oSelect[i].text; //or .value
    }
    var sel;
    sel = oSelect[oSelect.selectedIndex].text;
    alert (sel + ' : ' + def);
}

function resetSelect(oSelect) {
for (var i=0; i<oSelect.options.length; ++i) //loop through select options
if (oSelect.options[i].defaultSelected) //this option's defaultSelected property is set to true (from HTML: selected="selected")
oSelect.options[i].selected = true; //so, set its selected property to true, selecting it
showOptionValue(oSelect); //reset status
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<!-- call handler function, pass Select object (represents drop-down list) -->
<SELECT NAME="cbo" onchange="showOptionValue(this)"> 
<OPTION VALUE="not_default">Not DEFAULT VALUE</OPTION> 
<OPTION VALUE="1">Small</OPTION>
<!-- default value, preselected --> 
<OPTION VALUE="2" selected="selected">Medium</OPTION> 
<OPTION VALUE="3">Large</OPTION> 
</SELECT>
<!-- call handler function, pass Select object using its name as a variable -->
<input type="button" value="Reset Drop-down" onclick="resetSelect(cbo)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Totally irrelevant to the question.. he didn't ask about getting the **current** value, but the default value: the value that was initially selected..

Comment: Sorry, your code will still get only the current selected value and that's not what been asked here.

Comment: I didn't see your first comment until after I edited, and realized the whole thing was wrong. :( I've done a complete edit, hopefully it's the right answer. Work likes to distract me from answering SO questions.

Comment: @Nija:I need default and changed value on onchange evenet.

Comment: @raj - That is what my last edit (the HTML page) has. The alert will show both. The `def` variable contains the default value and the `sel` variable contains the selected value.

Comment: @Nija :Suppose take this scenario,by default i am showing one as my option value.i changed it to two,your code showing correct values,when i change two to three,it should show default as two and current as three.But your code showing default as still one,Actually it should show two.

Comment: @Raj - You're not wanting the default value then, but the previous value; ob's answer shows a way to do that. My answer shows the default/initial value. (not sure how it'll work if nothing was selected)

Comment: @Nija:is it possible to do present selected value as default one on onchange event,in this case we always get previous and present values correctly.

Comment: @raj - I think we're using different words for the same thing. Default, to me, is the initial value. Which my example shows. If you want the previous value, which your post (2 up) seems to show, then my answer won't give you the results you want, but is accurate by how I interpreted the question. :)

Comment: Undone the -1 but your `resetSelect` is IE only, standard browser don't have `document.all` which is used when you have something like `resetSelect(cbo)` - only IE is "generous" enough to search the whole document for something called `cbo`. To have it work in all browsers, pass the real object using something like `this.form.elements['cbo']`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Tested in FF 3.6 & 4 and Chrome 10; The `resetSelect` works. It may not be best practice and a hold-over from the source I used - but does work in FF and Chrome.

Comment: @Nija - yes now it's working.. weird. Still, better using `getElementById` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<SELECT ID="TEST" NAME="TEST" ONCHANGE="TEST(this)">
    <OPTION ID="1" VALUE="TEST1" SELECTED>TEST 1</OPTION>
    <OPTION ID="2" VALUE="TEST2">TEST 2</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

javascript:

```
// store currently selected value
var previousValue = document.getElementById('TEST').value;

function TEST(e) {
    alert('old value = ' + previousValue);
    alert('new value = ' + e.value);
    // store new value
    previousValue = e.value;
}
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/6vRr4/)

Comment: previous value as global variable,even i can't hardcode selectbox id also.is it possible to do this by placing previousvalue variable inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello world</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function fn(){
   var select = document.getElementById("selectbox");
   alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value)
   
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <header style="margin-left: 50%;">Welcome</header>
 <select id="selectbox">
  <option value="number 01">Number 01</option>
  <option value="number 01">Number 02</option>
  <option value="number 01">Number 03</option>
  <option value="number 01">Number 04</option>
 </select>
 <button style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:15px;" onclick="fn()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```